# How to decode Base64 variable in beforesend Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it at all possible to pass a variable, that is encoded in Base64, to the beforeSend function in an Ajax call, decode said variable and then pass that decoded variable to data? My code below does not pass the new encoded value to data.

```
const tokenData = {
    "ClientId": "<?php echo $api_clientId; ?>",
    "ClientSecret": "<?php echo $api_clientSecret; ?>",
    "MemberId": "<?php echo $api_memberId; ?>"
};

var encoded = btoa(JSON.stringify(tokenData));
console.log(encoded);
var decoded = JSON.parse(atob(encoded));
console.log(decoded);

var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": Url,
    "beforeSend": function() {
        encoded = JSON.parse(atob(encoded));
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": encoded
}
console.log(settings);
```

Comment: You're using the value of `encoded` when you create the `settings` variable. Reassigning the variable in `beforeSend:` doesn't replace that.

Comment: @Barmar any suggestions on a workaround to this? I've tried defining another variable in beforeSend and it does not recognize the variable in data for reasons that you've just stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeSend` receives the `settings` object as its second argument, you can use that to update the `data` option.

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": Url,
    "beforeSend": function(jqXHR, settings) {
        settings.data = atob(encoded);
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

I removed `JSON.parse()`. Since you're sending `application/json`, it needs to be the JSON string, not the parsed result.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, I need to remove "data:" from the settings variable so that beforeSend: can set it via the function?

Comment: you don't have to remove it, but it will be ignored since `beforeSend` replaces it.

Comment: It's not clear why you need to do this with `beforeSend`, though. Why not just do `data: atob(encoded)`?

Comment: Just didn't occur to me I suppose simple solutions are sometimes the hardest. This works perfectly by the way. Thank you very much